# ¿Como enviar desde un servlet con gson para que funcione un campo con la libreria typehead.js?

Tags: javascript, java, aplicación-web

Cuando coloco con json de forma local funciona el autocompletado.Ojoo estoy utilizando con la libreria tagsinput boopstrap.

```
/*var equipos = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('text'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: [
            {text: 'metronic', id: '2', estado: 'BUENO'},
            {text: 'keenthemes', id: '6', estado: 'INOPERATIVO'},
            {text: 'metronic theme', id: '5', estado: 'REGULAR'},
            {text: 'metronic template', id: '4', estado: 'BUENO'},
            {text: 'keenthemes team', id: '3', estado: 'REGULAR'}
        ]
    });*/
    /*local:           [
     {
     "id": "1",
     "text": "001 / COMPRESOR 1",
     "estado": "REGULAR"
     },
     {
     "id": "6",
     "text": "001001 / SUB COMPRESOR 1.0",
     "estado": "REGULAR"
     },
     {
     "id": "7",
     "text": "001002 / COMPRESOR 3",
     "estado": "BUENO"
     },
     {
     "id": "2",
     "text": "002 / COMPRESOR 2",
     "estado": "BUENO"
     },
     {
     "id": "10",
     "text": "003 / COMPRESOR CRISTAL 15*10",
     "estado": "INOPERATIVO"
     }
     ]*/
//   equipos.initialize();
```

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. ¿Dónde está el código Java, o del Servlet, o tu código JavaScript para consumir el servicio y trabajar con el resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que quieres hacer es algo parecido a un servicio REST, yo te recomendaría utilizar Spring y sus `@RestController` en lugar de Servlets.

Pero si no es posible, lo que necesitas es algo parecido a esto:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          JSONArray array= new JSONArray();
          response.setContentType("application/json");
          PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
          out.print(array);
          out.flush();
     }
```

Ya sólo te quedaría hacer peticiones con Javascript por GET al servlet.

`JSONArray` es un objeto de una librería llamada [JSON.simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple)

Pero supongo que es válido igual que para Guava.